# To find out when a particular user has cast his/her last vote

Tags: support, voting, users, votes, search

For many users/cases it is a trivial task to find out. For example, for me, [it is today only](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/4732/rickross?tab=topactivity) when I have cast my last vote.

But for many others, currently active or inactive, it is not possible to know this data easily.

For example, for the user [Amit Saxena](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/4157/amit-saxena?tab=topactivity), we can see that he hasn't cast a vote today, this week or even this month.

In case of such users can we find out the day they have cast their last vote on?

Is there any way by which we can find out the last time (day) a particular user has cast their last vote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it is generally hard to prove a negative, in this case I am confident that it is not possible to find out the time / day when a particular user has cast their latest vote, beyond the method that you've already mentioned. Voting is intended to be anonymous, and having too many tools to find out how someone has been casting their votes would go against this principle. As it happens, even with the limited amount of information available, it is possible for users to correctly guess the source of their downvotes [in some cases](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/128074/313042).

Of course, [moderators may be privy to some more information than regular users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/211115/313042), for the sake of identifying voting fraud, etc. But even they (probably?) cannot retrieve the exact data of when a user cast their latest vote.